# Какие измерения и метрики GA 3 можно заменить свойствами GA 4 (GA - Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

Существует старая версия Google Analytics, которая вычисляет количество посещений определенной страницы.

1. $result = $analytical->get($start_date, $end_date, "ga:pageviews", ["filters" => "ga:pagePath= мой URL"]); используется метрика "ga:pageviews" и фильтр по пути, а также другой код.
2. $result = $analytical->get($start_date, $end_date, "ga:users, ["filters" => "ga:landingPagePath= мой URL"]);

Необходимо перенести все в Google Analytics версии 4.

В первом случае вместо метрики "ga:pageviews" я использую totalUsers и фильтрую по pagePath. Как я узнал, "ga:pageviews" не был добавлен в версию 4, и пользователи рекомендуют использовать totalUsers.

Во втором случае я использовал totalUsers и фильтр по landingPage.

Также данные будут по меньше, чем в 3й версии. Все ли я сделал правильно, есть ли какая-нибудь страница, где собран список свойств версии 3 и как их можно заменить свойствами версии 4.

Те свойства, что я использовал, были взяты с [официального сайта](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema?hl=ru).

Клиент для работы с API с [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data)

Пожалуйста, посоветуйте, какие показатели следует использовать. Заранее спасибо